# c++ convert _bstr_t to int and convert int to _bstr_t

Tags: c++, int

I encouter a issue,here is my code,

```
          _bstr_t bstrTrans=L"2";
    wsprintf(buf,L"insert into inven(ID) values(%s)",(wchar_t *)bstrTrans)//insert into database
//this can work fine, now we want to let bstrTrans add 1, likes this
            int bstrTrans2 = atoi(bstrTrans) + 1;
    wsprintf(buf,L"insert into inven(ID) values(%s)",(wchar_t *)bstrTrans2 )
// now ,it cannot work.
```

so any body can help me?

Comment: You did not define the type `_b_str_t` so it is difficult to answer... Maybe using `snprintf` is relevant.

Comment: _bstr_t is a base data type in vc++

Comment: `bstrTrans2` is an `int` and you try to print it as a `wchar_t*`. That is not possible and will probably lead to a crash.

Comment: wow,you are right,it crashed, do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why not simple s -> d ?

```
    _bstr_t bstrTrans=L"2";
    wsprintf(buf,L"insert into inven(ID) values(%s)",(wchar_t *)bstrTrans) 

//insert into database
//this can work fine, now we want to let bstrTrans add 1, likes this
    int bstrTrans2 = atoi(bstrTrans) + 1;
    wsprintf(buf,L"insert into inven(ID) values(%d)",bstrTrans2 )
```

EDIT: hmm, this work?

```
    _bstr_t bstrTrans=L"2";
    wsprintf(buf,L"insert into inven(ID) values(%s)",(wchar_t *)bstrTrans) 

//insert into database
//this can work fine, now we want to let bstrTrans add 1, likes this
    char t[30];
    bstrTrans = itoa ( atoi (bstrTrans) + 1 , t,10);
    wsprintf(buf,L"insert into inven(ID) values(%s)",(wchar_t *)bstrTrans)
```

Comment: He he, well done ! But he may want to keep the string and not only to print it...

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but it should work fine:

```
const _wchar_t pBuffer[16] = {0};
wsprintf(pBuffer, L"%u", bstrTrans2)
_bstr_t bstrTrans3(pBuffer);
wsprintf(buf,L"insert into inven(ID) values(%s)",(wchar_t *)bstrTrans3 );
```

Comment: I want to let bstrTrans3=bstrTrans2+1

Comment: I don't understand... you want bstrTrans3 = bstrTrans2+1 = bstraTrans+2 ?